# Disable line item Fields on Custom Transaction Form

Tags: netsuite

1)Want to disable line item fields on Custom Transaction form.

Below is the snippet I tried & applied to the form's custom code on LINE INIT FUNCTION function but it doesn't work. Does it work or is it a bug or something I am missing here.Please suggest

```
function lineInit(){
    if(type == 'item'){  
        var itemDisFields = ['description','location'];

        for(var i = 0; i < itemDisFields.length; i++){
            nlapiDisableLineItemField('item',itemDisFields[i] , true);

        }

    }
    }
```

2)How to freeze Add button in the line level.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sublist indices in SuiteScript 1.0 start at `1`, not `0`, so you'll need to start `i` at `1`.
2. I am not exactly sure what you mean by "freeze" the Add button, but there is no *supported* way to do this. You could of course hack it with jQuery. The best *supported* way to prevent a line from being added is to use a `validateLine` handler and return `false` from it when the line should not be added.